# How can I register Java code as UDF or custom function with BigQuery SQL?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have one usecase where i need to do some computation on rows which are usecase specific. i want to write custom transformations in java and register it as UDF in BigQuery. so that with BigQuery SQL i can use it like function.

How i can do it? anybody knows the process to register java code with BigQuery?

Comment: For now, you can't use Java code to define functions. But a new feature, named remote function, will allow you to deploy a Cloud Functions in the language of your choice and to call it directly from bigQuery. For now, the feature is in private preview, you can register if you want. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not possible. You can use only JavaScript as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions).

As mentioned by @guillaumeblaquiere, you could try using [remote functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions) with [cloud functions in Java](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-java)